# GenericsMethod to Call Data Access layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, generics

I am Creating an Apllication with 3 tier Architecture.

- UI(web)
- BLL(ClassLibrary)
- DAL (ClassLibrary)

My need is i was binding Drop down list like Roles,Cities,Country,States...etc

I have Created Property(all will have the same structure) for all entities,Like

```
public class City
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Consider the below example of an Console application that replicates my need

**Suppose this call is from my UI**

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{

    List<City> cities = GetDataList<City>();
    List<Role> roles = GetDataList<Role>();

}
```

**This is my Business Logic (BLL)**

```
public static  List<T> GetDataList<T>() where T:class ,new()
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
 (A)   List<T> data = ** I am not getting the way how to call different methods of data acess here?
    foreach (var temp in data.AsEnumerable())
    {
        var obj = new T();
  ( B)     foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
            propertyInfo.SetValue(obj , Convert.ChangeType(temp. , propertyInfo.PropertyType) , null);
        }
        list.Add(obj);
    }

    return list;
}
```

**This is my DataAcess layer,i am using EF in here**

```
public static IList<City> FetchCityData()
{
    List<City> dict = new List<City>();           
    dict.Add(new City{Id="1",Name="hello"});
   dict.Add(new City{Id="2",Name="world"});
    return dict;
}

public static List<Role> FetchStateData()
{
    List<Role> dict = new List<Role>();
    dict.Add(new Role { Id = "1" , Name = "hello" });
    dict.Add(new Role { Id = "2" , Name = "world" });
    return dict;
}
```

My Questions Are:

A) how to access different Dataacess method from BLL?

B) how will I assign values to my class property here?

A and B are labels in the code.

Comment: simply branch code. You have 2 different methods `FetchCityData` and `FetchStateData`, there is no way to generalize it. The only input you have   is the type `T`, branching from that.

Comment: do you have access right to modify `City` and `Role` classes? If possible you could make some base class or some interface exposing a method like `FetchData`. That means you replace all the methods `FetchCityData` and `FetchStateDate` with detailed implementations.

Comment: yes i do have rights to modify `city` and All

Comment: and i am not buying it, that you said  "there is no way to generalize it"

Comment: I would add an attribute to the methods(with the corresponding class name). Then add a conditional:  " if typeof(T).Name == City". then Invoke method with the attribute of "City". Nice, generic and clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is branching code as I said. However you can make it neater via some `Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>` declared inside a helper class like this:

```
public static class DataFetcher {
    static Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> _fetchers;
    static Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> Fetchers {
      get {
          if(_fetchers == null) _fetchers = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>();
          return _fetchers;
      }
    }
    static DataFetcher(){
       Fetchers[typeof(City)] = FetchCityData;
       Fetchers[typeof(State)] = FetchStateData;
    }
    public static IList<T> FetchData<T>(){
       Func<object> f;
       if(Fetchers.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out f)){
           return (IList<T>) f();
       }
       return null;
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
public static  List<T> GetDataList<T>() where T:class ,new()
{
    var data = DataFetcher.FetchData<T>();
    //...
}
```

Still don't understand your second requirement.

Comment: I do have a interface, and my data Access methods are not static in application, i just created an Console Application to replicate my need :)... what do you suggest now!

Comment: @ShekharPankaj so it's hard to tell what exactly you have now. Maybe you should have posted your actual code (shorten as much as possible but don't change its designed structure).

Comment: Please suggest what if it is like this!, i want to learn thus way, rest i will manage..

Comment: @ShekharPankaj what do you mean? The code I posted here fits well with  your current code. If you want to re-design your code, the code here may be useless, otherwise it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your DAL design is wrong.

If you have a lot of generic calls like that in you business layer, you should expose generic data accessor in your DAL (if you're using EF, that's plain and simple).

That means that

1. You should establish a common interface for such items, such as

   ```
   public interface IReferenceData
   {
       string Id { get; set; }
       string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. You should expose generic method to fetch it

   ```
   public IEnumerable<T> GetReferenceData<T>() where T: IReferenceData
   ```

This way your BLL will be as simple as

```
public static List<T> GetDataList<T>() where T: IReferenceData
{
    return Dal.GetReferenceData<T>().ToList()
}
```

(although you just don't need BLL in this case)

*Update*: actually, you don't need the interface, I'm just used to do things this way so that I can add some processing to BLL. The question does not require it.

Comment: How could `IReferenceData` be used for `City` and `State`? They are totally different kind of items and can contain totally different kinds of info. `City` and `State` may have some common properties easily but when it comes to some other entity types, we simply cannot use an interface for them.

Comment: Actually, you don't need this interface unless you want to do something inside the BLL method. I will update.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what you can easily do is to introduce [Repository](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/getting-started-with-repository-pattern-using-C-Sharp/) pattern into your application. Remember, Repository is an interface in Domain layer (BLL), implemented in Infrastructure layer (DAL goes there). Generic repositories usually have a base class, that encapsulates all of the basic CRUD operations for all Entity and Identity(key) types.

Then you can bind interface to implementation using [Dependency Injection](https://jasenhk.wordpress.com/2013/06/11/unit-of-work-and-repository-pattern-with-unity-dependency-injection/) library (repository interface in [Domain layer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dn342868.aspx)), or even better, create Application layer, which contracts(interfaces) will be your use cases and the implementation will be [the glue](http://www.herrodius.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/LayeredArchitecture.png) code, that ties domain and infrastructure code to perform said use case(s). Read more on [Domain Driven Design](http://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-in-practice) about that.

That said, there is a more modern way to interact with a storage - implement [Command & Query segregation](http://www.bjoernrochel.de/2008/11/20/command-query-separation/). Where all of your data reads are [queries](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) and writes are [commands](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91). Both of them will also have a generic base that encapsulates a lot of logic. Instead of Repositories, that can be bloated with a lot of methods you will get a lot separate command & query classes that will be (hopefully) easier to manage.

Take a look a the provided links, its not that rocket science actually and all of the pieces easily fit a big picture with time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to get the data layer type and use MethodInfo.Invoke to call a method by a string name, utilising the type name of the return type you want. I have whipped up a quick example, but can't test it out as I'm on my phone!

```
Type dalType = Type.GetType("dalnamespace")

MethodInfo methodInfo = dalType.GetMethod(string.Format("Fetch{0}Data", objectTypeStringHere)); 
var returnValue = (List<T>)methodInfo.Invoke(dalType, null);
```

Comment: Amazing, I was thinking something similar!

Comment: While I'm glad you like my answer, I should point out what others have said, in that it may well be beneficial to utilise interfaces and a common method, like Serg has suggested :-)

Comment: I respectfully decline...The solution does not scale and is locked down to specific properties.

Comment: Fair enough :-) it was in response to the information available, which would suggest the items in scope if using this method had the same properties. At least you have an answer to whichever path you decide to choose with this!